# Formatting an sql column to contain only time in minutes

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL table that has this data

[image: sql Table column data]

I need the data to be formatted so that instead of showing this string of numbers and characters, I want to show time in minutes without the string. For example (in minutes):

```
88
85
85
67
63
76
71
75
75
42
```

Comment: I would ask *why* are you storing data in that format in the first place. Fixing your design is *hopefully* the reason for this question. Could you have any other denominators? Days, for example? If something is *exactly* *x* hours, would the value be `1 hour` or `1 hour 0 mins`. If you have multiple hours does it state "x hours" instead (of x hour)? If you have a sigular minute would it say `'1 min'`?

Answer (score 1):

I echo with Larnu comment.

You can try something like below.

```
declare @string varchar(20) = '1 hour 28 mins'


Select @string,case when CHARINDEX('hour',@string)>1 then 
                   SUBSTRING(@string,1,CHARINDEX('hour',@string)-1) * 60 else 0 end
               + 
               case when CHARINDEX('mins',@string)>1 then 
                    SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('mins',@string)-3,2) else 0 end
```